# Using kivy, why are the rectangles not changing colors?

Tags: colors, kivy

I am using the second edition of Kivy-Interactive Applications and Games in Python. The rectangles are supposed to be grey, but they only are white. I downloaded some code from the book off git hub that is supposed to return diagonal red lines, but its white also. Any help would be appreciated, I might just be missing something simple.

```
# File name: color.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        color: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.x + 10, self.y + 10
                size: self.width - 20, self.height - 20
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.x + 10, self.y + 10
                size: self.width - 20, self.height  - 20
""")

class LabelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things here.
Your color shall be capitalized, like this `Color`. And must be inside the `canvas`.
Then it shall contain, `rgba` forexample.

Try this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color: 
                rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.x + 10, self.y + 10
                size: self.width - 20, self.height - 20
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.x + 10, self.y + 10
                size: self.width - 20, self.height  - 20
""")

class LabelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelApp().run()
```

Comment: I knew that would work. I just copied what the book had. I just though the lower case color was something new and I had done it wrong.

Comment: @BradleyRay well there you have it. That is what is wrong. As you said, probably something simple :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @BradleyRay any time my friend :)